# on-page-layout in iframe - Firefox messes up

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

I am currently working on a one-page-layout, in which I've put an iframe of another one-page-layout.
Chrome and IE are doing well, but Firefox seems to mess with me.

http://neu.createk-medien.de

Just click on an item (currently every item opens the same iframe) and see for yourself.

Be aware the page is work in progress.

main-page:

```
<div id="tablet" class="box">
<div id="close_tablet" onclick="tablet_weg()">x</div>
<iframe src="http://tablet.createk-medien.de"></iframe>
</div>
```

the actual iframe is a lot of code and a really got no idea what causes the issues.

EDIT:
Solved it.
Firefox actually hates "display: none" on iframes.
Bypassed it with "visibility: hidden".

Comment: Please also include the code and what do you think it's the problem, if you get some errors or other useful informations.

Comment: It is pretty weird that Firefox acts like this.
Is there another solution? "display: none;" is a lot better for the overall performance than "visibility: hidden;"